# Conectar xcode simulator a Firebase

Tags: firebase, xcode

necesito conectar mi emulador de iphone (Lo corro con Xcode) al firebase.

Como primer paso, la documentacion de firebase me pide esto:

En Xcode, selecciona Product > Scheme > Edit scheme…
Selecciona Run en el menú de la izquierda.
Selecciona la pestaña Arguments.
En la sección Arguments Passed On Launch, agrega -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled.

Pero al hacer click en Edit Scheme no pasa nada, no se abre ninguna ventana y no me deja entrar a esas opciones

Comment: Puedes estructurar mejor la pregunta, y dejar imagenes sobre cuales son los errores ya que no se entiende

Comment: `Edit Scheme` si funciona. Intenta actualizar Xcode o cerrarlo y volverlo a abrir. Si el proyecto tiene un archivo `.xcworkspace`, debes abrir y trabajar en ese archivo.